# How to continue timer after page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

Currently, I have this JavaScript in my codes

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
      minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 0.18,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display); //`enter code here`
};
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

How do I keep my timer running when I refresh? Is using cookies the only way?

Comment: cookies or localstorage

Comment: or query parameters.

Comment: you can use cookie or local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was just pointers on how to make cookies, here is working code. Check out the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/hht4yqka/1/ you will need to tweak the timer, I have it set to 10:00.

```
  <script>
  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function() {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      setCookie("minutes", minutes.toString(), 1);
      setCookie("seconds", seconds.toString(), 1);

      if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = 0;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }


  window.onload = function() {
     var minutes_data = getCookie("minutes");
     var seconds_data = getCookie("seconds");
     var timer_amount = (60*10); //default
      if (!minutes_data || !seconds_data){
        //no cookie found use default
      }
      else{
        timer_amount = parseInt(minutes_data*60)+parseInt(seconds_data)
      }

    var fiveMinutes = timer_amount,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display); //`enter code here`
  };

   function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
   } 

   function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }
   return "";
  } 

  </script>

  <div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think cookie is your best bet if you don't have something like a database on your server side and/or the user isn't logged in:

This might help get you started, define set and get cookie functions per

SET

```
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
 }
```

GET

```
function getCookie(cname) {
 var name = cname + "=";
 var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
 for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
 }
 return "";
}
```

Somewhere in your document, perhaps in your timer, set your cookies something like:

```
setCookie("minutes", minutes.toString(), 1);
setCookie("seconds", seconds.toString(), 1);
```

Then somewhere in your on load event set your variables via the get function something like:

```
minutes = getCookie("minutes");
seconds = getCookie("seconds");
```

Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: As this answer wasn't technically wrong, just more of a pointers based answer, I went ahead and posted another answer.